# Counting number of distributions

Tags: combinatorics

My question is the following:

In the parliament of some country there are $151$ seats filled by $3$ parties. How many possible distributions $(i,j,k)$ are there that give no party an absolute majority?

I first tried using stars and bars to find number of solutions of $i+j+k=151;\ 0\le i,j,k\le 76$ but what stumps is the $\le$ inequality.

The solution in the book reads:

> The conditions $1\le i\le 75,\ 76-i\le j\le 75$ give as number $\sum_{i=1}^{75}i=2850$

I understand the solution but I am still wondering whether my first idea could be also implemented.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea can be made to work. Call a distribution **bad** if some party has an absolute majority. We want to subtract the number of bads from the number obtained from the simple Stars and Bars calculation.

The number of bads is $3$ times the number of bads with party A getting $\ge 76$.

To count this, give party A $76$ seats. Then distribute the remaining $75$ among the **three** parties, using Stars and Bars to count the number of ways to do it.